# Can't get it how the function works

Tags: javascript

So basically i just started learning JS and had a little exercise which was basically making a function to check if the number is even without using modular arithmetic. When i was done with it i just wanted to compare mine with the answer and i couldn't really get how does it work.

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return true;
  else if (n == 1)
    return false;
  else if (n < 0)
    return isEven(-n);
  else
    return isEven(n - 2);
}
```

I'm not sure how the part (n-2) works does it somehow puts the number in a loop and basically does n-=2 until the number gets 1 or 0?

Comment: Yep. Basically. It uses recursion to do `n -= 2` until `n` becomes `1` or `0`.

Comment: Yes, function keeps iterating until the return true or return false

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126756/examples-of-recursive-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number is negative, the function makes it positive and runs itself again against the positive value, if it's > 1, it will run itself again until the number is 1 or 0, decreasing the number by 2 on each iteration. It's called recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at what is going on behind the scenes when this function is run:

```
isEven(8)
// isEven(8) Is 8 even?
//   isEven(6)  Is 6 even?
//     isEven(4)  Is 4 even?
//       isEven(2) Is 2 even?
//         isEven(0) Is 0 even? --> Yes, the function immediately returns true
// so I know the one at the top, 8, is even
```

And so on. For any even number, it eventually gets to 0. For any odd number it eventually gets to 1.

Comment: Note that when the 'bottom' function returns `true`, this is then the result that is returned from the next-to-last function, which is the result returned from the next-to-next-to-last function, on up to the very first.

Answer (score 0):

When n <0 it puts a minus before the n in the function and runs it again. If Else then the function is called again but n is decreased by 2. This runs till you get true or false.