# Calling a function recursively more than once

Tags: c, recursion, logic

I am new to programming, Please explain me the working of the below recursion function. The function is called recursively twice, Will the statements after the 1st recursive call gets executed?

```
void sort(int low, int high) {
   int mid;

   if(low < high) {
      mid = (low + high) / 2;
      sort(low, mid);
      sort(mid+1, high);
      merging(low, mid, high);
   } else { 
      return;
   }   
}
void main()
{
   sort(0, 10);
}
```

Comment: The `else { return; }` in sort really doesn’t help, especially since there isn’t a `return after the call to `merging()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets go line by line

1. First your sort function will run for arguments 0 and 10 this will be the first call to this function.
2. From line `if(low < high)` Since 0 < 10 then mid will be 5 : because of `mid = (low + high) / 2;`.
3. Now again the sort function will run now for args 0 and 5 this will be the second call to this function, but remember the first call is still not finished doing its job.
4. Since 0 < 5 then mid will be 2.
5. Now again the sort function will run this time for args 0 and 2 this will be third call and the second function will remain working.
6. since 0 < 2 mid will be 1.
7. Now again the sort function will run this time for args 0 and 1 this will be forth call and the third call to the function will remain working.
8. since 0 < 1 mid will be 0.
9. Now again the sort function will run this time for args 0 and 0 this will be fifth call and the forth call to the function will remain working.
10. since 0 < 0 is now false the return call in the else will be executed and this function will be destroyed. Now the control will go back to the forth call which was working for args 0 as low and 1 as high.
11. Now from the fifth line `sort(mid+1, high);`  of your code sort will be called again this time for low = 1 and high also = 1.
12. Now again the sort function will be called and this is the sixth call and this time it will run for args low = 1 and high = 1 and it will start executing from the first line of your code.

Consider this as a stack, first push `sort(0,10)` then => `sort(0,5)` then =>  `sort(0,2)` then =>  `sort(0,1)`  then =>  `sort(0,0)`

Now since `sort(0,0)` finished executing it will be removed from the stack and `sort(0,1)` will continue.
So it should look like this

`sort(0,10)` => `sort(0,5)` =>  `sort(0,2)` =>  `sort(0,1)`

Again in the fifth line of the `sort(0,1)` the call to `sort()` is there, so again sort will be pushed to this stack:

`sort(0,10)` => `sort(0,5)` =>  `sort(0,2)` =>  `sort(0,1)`  =>  `sort(1,1)`

This will goes on and finally the call to the `sort(0,10)` will finish executing and you will get your desired outcome.

Comment: i don't understood when sort(mid+1, high) start execute.. cause i could only get left side of the array.. right side suppose to be something: ``sort(mid+1, high) == sort(0,1) or sort(5,10).``  how this part will happens..

Answer (score 0):

see the Recursion example link from stack overflow.
[Examples of Recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126756/examples-of-recursive-functions)

What are you trying to achieve in the code? A recursion function should call the function itself and it should have the condition to stop otherwise it will go in infinite loop. The code you have written called the same function twice and which is not correct. You should call the function once and with stop condition.

Comment: `if (low < high)` is the condition to stop. And there's nothing wrong with recursing twice. This is basically quicksort.