# How Loop Through Again If User Inputs Wrong Word

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Basically, what I want my code to do is if the user inputs anything besides "sum, quit, max, min" I want the program to loop back and ask the user the options again. I tried using a while-loop but I can't add multiple String objects within it. I'm stuck on what to do. (Also, I used if-statements instead of while so it won't continually repeat and be stuck.)

EDIT: thank you for the help! I used a while(true), break statements, and a continue at the end and it seems to work!

```
public static void main (String [] args){
        System.out.println("Enter the option sum, max, min:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        user = input.nextLine();
        double [] y = theArray();


        if (user.equals("sum")){
            //do something

        }
        else if (user.equals("max")){
            //do something 
        }
        else if (user.equals("min")){
            //do something
        }
        else if (user.equals("Quit")){
            //do something
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't add multiple String objects within it"?

Comment: within a while loop you cant say while(user.equals("quit", "sum");

Comment: Use the `while` infinite loop and break it when the condition is met.

Comment: @csstudent2x oh, I get it. I didn't understand that's what he meant.

Comment: Just a comment on your note with the while statement; although you can't say `while(user.equals("quit", "sum")){` you *can* say `while(user.equals("quit") || user.equals("sum")){` , and add more `||`'s (Or's) as needed for anything else. If that logic makes more sense to you than the break or the recursion answers below, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

As I have said in the comment above, use the `while` infinite loop and `break` it when the condition is met. If the condition is not met, the loop goes for the next iteration. Keep aware what should be looped and why.

```
System.out.println("Enter the option sum, max, min:");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String option;

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println("Enter the option sum, max, min:");
    option = scanner.nextLine();
    if ("sum".equals(option)) {
        System.out.println("Sum entered, loop ended");
        // do something
        break;
    } else if ("max".equals(option)) { // the same goes for min, max, quit }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899657/how-should-you-approach-recursion):

```
public static void main (String [] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        promptUser(input);

        System.out.println("done");

    }
    public static void promptUser(Scanner input) {
        System.out.println("Enter the option sum, max, min:");
        String user = input.nextLine();
        double [] y = theArray();


        if (user.equals("sum")){
            //do something
        }
        else if (user.equals("max")){
            //do something
        }
        else if (user.equals("min")){
            //do something
        }
        else if (user.equals("Quit")){
            //do something
        }else {
            //if wrong input is entered, try again
            promptUser(input);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any idea if Java would optimize this into a tail recursive form?