# Is This A Good Example Of Recursion?

Tags: recursion

I realize this is a really simple bit of code, and I'm quite sure it's recursive, but I just want to make sure it is what I think it is.  (Sorry if this is kind of a lame question, I'm just second guessing myself on if I understand what recursion actually is.)

```
var x = 0
func countToTen() {
    if (x <= 10) {
        println(x)
        x++
        countToTen()
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally, I'd pass `x` *into* `countToTen` rather than using it globally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688019/recursion-versus-iteration some points of view here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely recursive! For good style, however, it is best to make x a parameter to the function. It's sort of a style issue, but it also makes the code easier to maintain to not have global variables like you have here.

here's what I'm talking about.

```
func countToTen(x) {
    if (x <= 10) {
        println(x)
        countToTen(x + 1)
    }
}
```

Now you can just call the function

```
countToTen(1)
```

And that would count from 1 to ten, for instance. You did it correctly, my version is just perhaps slightly cleaner form.

Answer (score -1):

In programming, if a method:

- Calls itself and,
- Moves towards a base case (in this case x == 10)

then it is recursive.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105838/real-world-examples-of-recursion) is a post about real-world examples.

Comment: Would a while loop there not just call another instance of the method? Leaving 9 methods continuously calling new methods?

Comment: Checked it in a [fiddle](http://swiftstub.com/) turns out if and while actually give the same output in this case, which is interesting because I don't think that would happen in most other languages.

Comment: Okay, I would have thought that a while loop would just call another instance of CountToTen 10 times, and so on which would call CountToTen something like 100000000 times? lol

Comment: Who knows ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I removed it anyways.